# Domain name issue on apache 2 server

Tags: apache

I have a Amazon ec2, apache 2 web server with that are accessible with the following domain names:

> example.com (have pointed the A record to elastic ip shown below)
>
> example.bitnamiapp.com (created while using bitnami-amazon ec2 dashboard)
>
> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (elastic ipv4 address)

How to prevent visiters to access my server by using ipv4 address or example.bitnamiapp.com while I would allow them to access my server with example.com only?